# django Incorrect authentication service "google-oauth2"

Tags: django

I am trying to get django-social-auth to work with google logins.

I logged into google dev console > created a project > created a new client id in credentials as a web application which gave me the id and secrete.

I then get an error when i click the link on my site to log on with google

```
WrongBackend at /login/google-oauth2/
Incorrect authentication service "google-oauth2"
```

Here is my settings in settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social.backends.yahoo.YahooOpenId',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/oauth2callback/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login-error/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user'
SOCIAL_AUTH_UID_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_NONCE_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 16

SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = 'google'

GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret'
```

Does anyone know why i get that message? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS you mentioned, it seems you use **python-social-auth** (not **django-social-auth**) which has another syntax of key and secrect declaration. 
references: [python-social-auth documentation](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/google.html?highlight=social_auth_google_oauth2_key)

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY     = 'id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET  = 'client_secret'
```